# WinRT - Is item rendered?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

Is it possible to check has item already been rendered (therefore visible to user) on screen? I am trying to create image control with automatic "image swapping animation" but when I have hundreds of images on page (for instance in GridView) performance is terrible. I'd like to know which controls are visible to user so I'd run animation only for them.

Comment: Did you tried ListView with virtualization? I can elaborate it if needed.

Comment: but how can I use it to get only rendered items?

Comment: When you bind collection to ListView with virualization, it will load only items that are visible. Each ListViewItem will be loaded right before presentation. So `Loaded` event will be fired right before showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the item's position by getting `UIElement.TransformToVisual()` and then using it to get the coordinates of the item relative to the clipping frame of the `ScrollViewer` in your `GridView`, but the performance of it might not be very good if you check it on each `ScrollViewer` view change event and could use some optimization, which would also be difficult if your GridView supports virtualization, which it needs to if you want to be able to scroll through hundreds of images.

Oleh's suggestion is your best best if you don't want to spend days or weeks figuring it out. Your `GridView` will be virtualized if you use a virtualizing panel for its `ItemsPanel` property, e.g. a `WrapGrid` (Windows 8.0 default) or `ItemsWrapGrid` (Windows 8.1 default). Note that `VariableSizedWrapGrid` is **NOT** virtualized.